# Creating Mailing list gives only one value instead of all in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to create mailing list in SSRS I did following instructions from this [pdf document](http://www.bscichicago.com/documents/CreatingAvery5160MailingLabelsSSRS.pdf).

on the expression I added following code but it is giving me only one address label when I do print out instead of giving me all the data in tables.

```
=(Fields!MAIL_FIRM_NME.Value, "dtsLimeActiveCompanyMailingLabels")+" "+(Fields!ID.Value, "dtsLimeActiveCompanyMailingLabels")+Environment.NewLine()+(Fields!MAIL_ADDR_1.Value, "dtsLimeActiveCompanyMailingLabels")+Environment.NewLine()+(Fields!MAIL_ADDR_2.Value, "dtsLimeActiveCompanyMailingLabels")+Environment.NewLine()+(Fields!MAIL_CTY.Value, "dtsLimeActiveCompanyMailingLabels")+" "+(Fields!MAIL_ST.Value, "dtsLimeActiveCompanyMailingLabels")+" "+(Fields!MAIL_ZIP.Value, "dtsLimeActiveCompanyMailingLabels")
```

Comment: What kind of container is this expression in?

Comment: I have put this in Textbox.

Comment: Ok, and what data-driven container is the textbox in?   A tablix or list?

Comment: If it is returning only one row, I assume you are using First(). You have to use a tablix, matrix or list SSRS components to show multiple rows.

Comment: It is in List container.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the expression, so the problem must be somewhere else.   Recommend you add screenshots of your List item to your question.